# Zipping folder of gz / tar type

Tags: zip, gzip

I am using tar ssh tectia client. I have to zip a folder with .zip extension in this.

In putty i used

```
zip -r Worker_image.zip BlobFiles Worker.dat
```

but this zip command is not identified in ssh tectia. It only identifies gz or tar command.

I tried the following :

```
tar -cvf Image.tar Image
```

and then gz

```
gzip Image.tar
```

This is giving me .tar.gz extension file. What i need is .zip extension as only this is readable by third party. Is there a way to create .zip folder in ssh tectia ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a misunderstanding here. Whether the zip programs works or not depends on whether it is installed on the server, not on the program you use to ssh to the server (which may be PuTTY, SSH Tectia, or whatever).

Although improbable, perhaps the `zip` program has been uninstalled from the server, and this explains why you can't find it out. In this case you'll need to transfer the original files to a server which has zip installed.

A more plausible explanation is that you're not calling the `zip` program correctly. Typing `whereis zip` will show you its location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not have installed zip program in your server , you must install it or you can download .tar.gz file to your computer and and you can unpack it with Winzip and compact it again to .zip file.